# NullPointerException in com.reg.project

Tags: android

I have no Idea why I get this error :/

```
Exception class java.lang.NullPointerException
    Source method Jax$7.onClick()



java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.reg.lolsoundboard.Jax$7.onClick(Jax.java:83)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9089)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3806)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously you are dereferencing a variable in line 83 of the file Jax.java where the variable is null.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.reg.lolsoundboard.Jax$7.onClick(Jax.java:83)
```

If show the relevant code, people may be able to help you.